# Use spacy Spanish Tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, spacy

I always used spacy library with english or german.

To load the library I used this code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

I would like to use the Spanish tokeniser, but I do not know how to do it, because spacy does not have a spanish model.
I've tried this

```
python -m spacy download es
```

and then:

```
nlp = spacy.load('es')
```

But obviously without any success.

Does someone know how to tokenise a spanish sentence with spanish in the proper way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For version till 1.6 this code works properly:

```
from spacy.es import Spanish
nlp = Spanish()
```

but in version 1.7.2 a little change is necessary:

```
from spacy.es import Spanish
nlp = Spanish(path=None)
```

Source:@honnibal in gitter chat

Comment: This didn't work for me. Maybe the API has been updated? See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295316/importerror-no-module-named-spacy-en

Answer (score 1):

You will have to download a spanish language model ("es" for Spanish, 'md' = medium model size,  'sm' = small model size) using the command line. Currently two pretrained Spanish models are available:

- es_core_news_sm
- es_core_news_md

Choose the small or medium sized version and download them using the command line:

```
python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
```

```
python -m spacy download es_core_news_md
```

Then load the model of choice in python using the name of the model:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm") # or spacy.load("es_core_news_md")

# do something with the model, e.g. tokenize the text
doc = nlp(text_in_spanish)
for token in doc:
   print(token.text)
```

Check the documentation for model updates:
https://spacy.io/models/es

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm


import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")
```