# Error while trying to run a simple chatterbot code in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, scapy, chatterbot

I have the latest python 3.9x and scapy version available and followed all the instructions on how to load scapy in but I still get the error
The error I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnyoP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2b5E.png)

I also tried to edit the tagging.py and languages.py files by adding the if else condition(tagging.py) and adding ‘en_core_web_sm’ (languages.py). Please help as I don’t understand why it isn’t working for me.
The code I try to run:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCOcZ.png)

Please help, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you don't have permission to download and use the model, please do all the steps with admin/root permission. The easiest way to modify a module in `spacy` would be inheritance and extend classes!

Comment: I am sorry, can you please elaborate a bit on it.

Comment: It's OK :)
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964028/spacy-oserror-cant-find-model-en) if you didn't before. @Ajitesh

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.