# encountering this error while making my own grammerly web application

Tags: python

I am trying to use gramformer to make my own grammar correction web application. 
When I run `gf = Gramformer(models = 1, use_gpu=False)` after importing gramformer, I am getting this error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16548/2071847133.py in <module>
----> 1 gf = Gramformer(models = 1, use_gpu=False)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gramformer\gramformer.py in __init__(self, models, use_gpu)
      6     #from lm_scorer.models.auto import AutoLMScorer as LMScorer
      7     import errant
----> 8     self.annotator = errant.load('en')
      9 
     10     if use_gpu:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\errant\__init__.py in load(lang, nlp)
     14 
     15     # Load spacy
---> 16     nlp = nlp or spacy.load(lang, disable=["ner"])
     17 
     18     # Load language edit merger

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in load(name, **overrides)
     28     if depr_path not in (True, False, None):
     29         warnings.warn(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path), DeprecationWarning)
---> 30     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
     31 
     32 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model(name, **overrides)
    173     elif hasattr(name, "exists"):  # Path or Path-like to model data
    174         return load_model_from_path(name, **overrides)
--> 175     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
    176 
    177 

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package, or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I also tried reinstalling spacy but it's not working

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49964028/5320906)