# Azure Python Deployment - Spacy nomodule found exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I'm using Linux App Service. I'm trying to deploy python 3.6 flask application through the Azure DevOps pipeline. It worked fine for a basic app but when I add an additional code (spacy module), it started to throw

```
2019-12-24T18:07:33.079953940Z     __import__(module)
2019-12-24T18:07:33.079961840Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/application.py", line 3, in <module>
2019-12-24T18:07:33.079970340Z     from Data_Cleanup_utility.clear_content_utility import ClearContent
2019-12-24T18:07:33.079978440Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/Data_Cleanup_utility/clear_content_utility.py", line 12, in <module>
2019-12-24T18:07:33.079986741Z     import spacy
2019-12-24T18:07:33.079994741Z **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'**
2019-12-24T18:07:33.084726683Z [2019-12-24 18:07:33 +0000] [51] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 51)
2019-12-24T18:07:33.170423056Z [2019-12-24 18:07:33 +0000] [48] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-12-24T18:07:33.172257711Z [2019-12-24 18:07:33 +0000] [48] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I have added the dependency modules in the **requirement.txt**

```
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
fastai==1.0.59
numpy==1.17.4
pandas==0.25.3
requests==2.22.0
spacy==2.2.3
spacy-langdetect==0.1.2
```

and **azurepipeline.yml**

```
- script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        python -m spacy download es
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"
```

and my code **clear_content_utility.py**

```
import spacy
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector

nlp = spacy.load('es')
nlp.add_pipe(LanguageDetector(), name='language_detector', last=True)
```

did anyone face the above issue? appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you should do:

- Please ensure to activate the virtual environment before executing any code, also make sure to check if your installed package is actually in there in your VENV.

I would suggest you to create new VENV and try activating it.

- Secondly , you can language data has been moved to a submodule `**spacy.lang**` to keep thing cleaner and better organised.

  **E.g**. instead of using **`spacy.en`**, you now import from **`spacy.lang.en`**

```js
    python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Additional reference:

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/13328/

[ImportError: No module named 'spacy.en'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295316/importerror-no-module-named-spacy-en)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to activate the new virtual environment but still, it's only taking base python.

Comment: try Creating a new venv by virtualenv with option "--no-site-packages"

virtualenv --no-site-packages --python=/xx/xx/bin/python my_env_nmae

Comment: There are multiple issues with deployment. Azure Pipeline had a problem. I have resolved it using Viscose. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, @Siva I am facing the same issue. Could you please detail what you did to fix it?

Comment: @Royston46 you need to add the following configuration in Azure Web App to activate/use the virtualenv which you created and installed all the dependency.
*WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1*
if you're not adding this configuration, the web app still use the base python.